# Python: Open file in zip without temporarily extracting it

Tags: python, zip

How can I open files in a zip archive without extracting them first?

I'm using pygame. To save disk space, I have all the images zipped up.
Is it possible to load a given image directly from the zip file? 
For example:
`pygame.image.load('zipFile/img_01')`

Comment: What kind of image files? GIF, JPEG, and PNG are already compressed.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Vincent Povirk's answer won't work completely;

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('images.zip', 'r')
imgfile = archive.open('img_01.png')
...
```

You have to change it in:

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('images.zip', 'r')
imgdata = archive.read('img_01.png')
...
```

For details read the `ZipFile` docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open).

Comment: image = pygame.image.load(imgfile, 'img_01.png')
TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str

Comment: Please explain your change. read returns a string with the file's contents; open returns a file-like object. pygame's documentation says image.load wants a filename or file-like object.

Comment: @Vincent Povirk: Thanks for commenting. The problem remains that image.load does accept a file-like object, but doesn't accept the zip-file-object. You have to adapt to that somehow. I'm not convinced of my answer either, it's not elegant yet...

Comment: I agree with @EsmePovirk. The cited documentation seems to suggest that both `.read()` and `.open()` do not create temp files and provide `bytes` streams. The difference seems to be that `.open()` can be used as a context manager and supports seeking the reading position, while `.read()` reads the whole file.

Answer (score 33):

```
import io, pygame, zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('images.zip', 'r')

# read bytes from archive
img_data = archive.read('img_01.png')

# create a pygame-compatible file-like object from the bytes
bytes_io = io.BytesIO(img_data)

img = pygame.image.load(bytes_io)
```

I was trying to figure this out for myself just now and thought this might be useful for anyone who comes across this question in the future.

Answer (score 23):

From Python 3.2 onwards it has been possible to use the `ZipFile` as a context manager:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('images.zip') as zf:
    for file in zf.namelist():
        if not file.endswith('.png'): # optional filtering by filetype
            continue
        with zf.open(file) as f:
            image = pygame.image.load(f, namehint=file)
```

- The plus side of using context managers (`with` statement) is that the files are automatically closed properly.
- The `f` can be used like regular [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) you would get when using the built-in [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

#### Links to documentation

- [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile), [ZipFile.namelist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist), [ZipFile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)
- [PEP 343 (with statement)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 14):

In theory, yes, it's just a matter of plugging things in. Zipfile can give you a file-like object for a file in a zip archive, and image.load will accept a file-like object. So something like this should work:

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('images.zip', 'r')
imgfile = archive.open('img_01.png')
try:
    image = pygame.image.load(imgfile, 'img_01.png')
finally:
    imgfile.close()
```