# Python: how to pass a file from a zip to a function that reads data from that file

Tags: python, zip

I have a zip-file that contains [.nrrd](https://github.com/mhe/pynrrd) type files. The pynrrd lib comes with a read function. How can I pull the `.nrrd` file from the zip and pass it to the `nrrd.read()` function?

I tried following, but that gives the following error at the `nrrd.read()` line:

> TypeError was unhandled by user code, file() argument 1 must be
>   encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

```
in_dir = r'D:\Temp\Slikvideo\JPEG\SV_4_1_mask'
zip_file = 'Annotated.mitk'

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(in_dir + '\\' + zip_file)

f_name = 'datafile.nrrd'    # .nrrd file in zip

file_nrrd = zf.read(f_name)    # pull the file from the zip

img_nrrd, options = nrrd.read(file_nrrd)    # read the .nrrd image data from the file
```

I could write the file pulled from the .zip to disk, and then read it from disk with `nrrd.read()` but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your is a good way...

Here there is a similar question:

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371860/python-open-file-from-zip-without-temporary-extracting-it)

Plus answer: 
I think that the problem maybe is that when you use zipfile.ZipFile you not set the attribute:
Try using:

```
zipfile.ZipFile (path,"r")
```

Comment: Adding "r" gives same error. I checked your Similar Question, but it's different as the file is passed to a pygame.load() function and the solution that is given is what I already have and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
file_nrrd = zf.extract(f_name)    # extract the file from the zip
```