# Loading nii.zip (compressed) 3d segmentation files

Tags: image-segmentation, nifti

I know SimpleITK can read 3d images in Nifty (.nii) format, and also that it supports nii.gz compressed version. However, I am not able to load nii.zip files. These files throw error if I try to unzip/extract them directly, and also not recognized as one of the readable formats by SimpleITK.

Dataset for reference can be found in: https://academictorrents.com/details/27772adef6f563a1ecc0ae19a528b956e6c803ce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the same dataset a while ago, I did not experiment with it thoroughly, but here is my experience:

1. **I am able to unzip the nii.zip files succesfully**

   - I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and preinstalled unzipping utility from GUI
   - The problems you are experiencing could be happening due to using different archive manager or maybe the dataset could have been damaged during download
   - **solution** - try different archive manager and download the dataset again
2. **I am using Aliza to view the unzipped scans**

   - from my experience for quick checking of the medical image formats [Aliza viewer](https://www.aliza-dicom-viewer.com/) is the best program available with possible exports to different formats
3. **Solution for reading zipped files**

   - if you are using SimpleITK or (my favourite in python) [Nibabel](https://nipy.org/nibabel/) and want to read the zipped files directly you can refer to these answers how to tackle the problem of reading the files inside the zipped archives - [Stack overflow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48456420/accessing-files-inside-a-zip-archive-without-extracting-them) and [Stack overflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371860/python-open-file-from-zip-without-temporary-extracting-it)

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to use nibabel with a zip file, it kept complaining. Instead, I wrote each file out to a temp directory so it would be a real file on the file system. Not graceful, but it works.

```
# import required modules
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import zipfile
import shutil

working_dir = '/work/nifti_volume/'

my_zip_path = working_dir + 'raw.zip'
temp_dir = working_dir + 'temp'

z = zipfile.ZipFile(my_zip_path, "r")

for filename in z.namelist(  ):
    if not filename[-1] == '/': # skip over folders in zip file
        
        print('File:', filename)        
        z.extract(filename, path=temp_dir)
        
        nii = nib.load(temp_dir + '/' + filename)
        img = nii.get_fdata()

        # Get voxel dimensions
        voxel_dims = (nii.header["pixdim"])[1:4]
        
        # Compute volume
        nonzero_voxel_count = np.count_nonzero(img)
        voxel_volume = np.prod(voxel_dims)
        nonzero_voxel_volume = nonzero_voxel_count * voxel_volume

        # https://neurostars.org/t/calculate-volumes-counting-voxels-is-a-correct-approach/1433/8
        
        print("Number of non-zero voxels = {}".format(nonzero_voxel_count))
        print("Volume of non-zero voxels = {} mm^3".format(nonzero_voxel_volume))

        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```