# Use Ramdisk in linux without access file directly

Tags: python, linux, ram, ramdisk

I need to extract a zip file in RAM with my python script.
I have searched about Ramdisk in linux and I have some experiences in using Ramdisk.
It's Ok for me but it has a big problem.
Everyone who access my directories can see the unzipped file that I extracted them there (in Mounted Ramdisk), I need to access those unzipped files but it is necessary that only my python script can read and write file in RAM.
Do you have a better way for my program? Or a solution for this problem?
Thanks.

edit:
It has to be possible to interact with extracted files like normal files in a directory.
not just open and read them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: Open file from zip without temporary extracting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371860/python-open-file-from-zip-without-temporary-extracting-it)

Comment: The only way you would be able to "interact" with the extracted files outside of the python program is if they're placed on a ramdisk. Python does not come with software to create one.

Comment: I can run os commands by my python program to create RamDisk, but I want only my python script access those files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a secure temporary directory under `/dev/shm` and then extract the zip file into that. Due to its unpredictable name and tight permissions, only your user will be able to interact with it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory