# Storing many small files (on S3)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 million zipped HTML files (100-150KB) being added each day that I need to store for a long time.
Hot data (70-150 million) is accessed semi regularly, anything older than that is barely ever accessed.

This means each day I'm storing an additional 200-300GB worth of files.

Now, Standard storage costs $0.023 per GB and $0.004 for Glacier.

While Glacier is cheap, the problem with it is that it has additional costs, so it would be a bad idea to dump 2 million files into Glacier:

`PUT requests to Glacier $0.05 per 1,000 requests`

`Lifecycle Transition Requests into Glacier $0.05 per 1,000 requests`

Is there a way of gluing the files together, but keeping them accessible individually?

Comment: Store as single ZIP file to save storage. When accessing, extract ZIP and serve one file

Comment: @Justinas this means the files won't be accessible individually.

Comment: It would via proxy service

Comment: Whatever you end up doing, if you create one large archive file, you end up needing to get the entire file out of glacier, and then you can pull down parts of it using byte range requests.  Also, retrieving files from glaciers takes time, hours in some cases.  Personally, I'd look into Standard IA, and creating a bespoke archive format that has a header with contents at the beginning, so you could use byte-range requests to read the header, then get the data once you know where it is.  Perhaps wrap the complexity of retrieval in a Lambda so clients don't need to know what's going on.

Comment: Glacier costs $0.004 as you wrote. But you can't use deep archive which cost 4 times less ($0.00099)?

Answer (score 5):

An important point, that if you need to provide quick access to these files, then Glacier can give you access to the file in **up to 12 hours**. So the best you can do is to use `S3 Standard – Infrequent Access` (0,0125 USD per GB with millisecond access) instead of `S3 Standard`. And maybe for some really not using data `Glacier`. But it still depends on how fast do you need that data.

Having that I'd suggest following:

- as html (text) files have a good level of compression, you can **compress historical data in big zip files** (daily, weekly or monthly) as together they can have even better compression;
- **make some index file or database** to know where each html-file is stored;
- read only desired html-files from archives **without unpacking whole zip-file**. See [example in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19372080) how to implement that.

Comment: You're perfectly right, the problem is indexing these files.

Comment: @Buffalo so you can accept this answer now.

Comment: I will as soon as someone answers "Is there a way of gluing the files together, but keeping them accessible individually?". Because downloading huge zips isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

Glacier would be extremely cost sensitive when it comes to the number of files. The best method would be to create a Lambda function that handles zip, unzip operations for you.

Consider this approach:

- Lambda creates `archive_date_hour.zip` of the 2 Million files from that day by hour, this solves the "per object" cost problem by creating 24 giant archival files.
- Set a `policy` on the `s3` bucket to move expired objects to glacier over 1 day old.
- Use an unzipping Lambda function to fetch and extract potential hot items from the glacier bucket from within the zip files.
- Keep the main `s3` bucket for hot files with high frequent access, as a working directory for the zip/unzip operations, and for collecting new files daily

Answer (score 2):

Your files are just too small. You will need to combine them probably in an ETL pipeline such as glue. You can also use the `Range` header i.e. `-range bytes=1000-2000` to download part of an object on `S3`.

If you do that you'll need to figure out the best way to track the bytes ranges, such as after combining the files recording the range for each one, and changing the clients to use the `range` as well.

The right approach though depends on how this data is accessed and figuring out the patterns. If somebody who looks at `TinyFileA` also looks at `TinyFileB` you could combine them together and just send them both along with other files they are likely to use. I would be figuring out logical groupings of files which make sense to consumers and will reduce the number of requests they need, without sending too much irrelevant data.