# Why freesansbold.ttf can't be found after i put in library.zip pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, pygame, tic-tac-toe

```
C:\Users\ABDUL HAIYAN\Desktop\Programming\Python\Tic Tac Toe\dist>tictactoe
    pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.8)
    Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tictactoe.py", line 181, in <module>
    File "tictactoe.py", line 47, in game_opening
    File "tictactoe.py", line 60, in draw_status
    File "pygame\pkgdata.pyc", line 84, in getResource
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ABDUL HAIYAN
    \\Desktop\\Programming\\Python\\Tic Tac Toe\\dist\\library.zip\\pygame\\freesans
    bold.ttf'
```

The Files already in there:

[image: The Files already in there]

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think pygame can load things from within zip files.

Comment: Starbuck5 is right - You have to read the files [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371860/python-open-file-in-zip-without-temporarily-extracting-it) if you want Python to see them in a `.zip` (`.zip` does not work as a folder for Python).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read [this page](https://pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_text/text.html) to familiar you with the `pygame.font` module.

## 3 Ways to get the file:

### 1. Unzip the needed file.

In this case, you should open the `.zip` with Python, then extract the `.ttf` file, you open it / read it as you want, then delete the extracted font file.

If you want Python to open a file within a `.zip` file, you should use the [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module like that:

```py
import zipfile # needed to extract the font file
import pygame

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('files.zip', 'r') # the .zip containing your files
font_file = archive.open('font.ttf') # the font.ttf file is ready to be read
archive.close()

pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(font_file, 20) # the font is initialised

... # do some stuff
```

---

### 2. Use [`pygame.font.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont)

This module imports a font from the system fonts (i.e. the fonts available in Word, etc)

Syntax:

```
pygame.font.SysFont('font name', font_size)
```

For example:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans Ms', 20)
```

In this case you don't even need a `.ttf` file.

---

### 3. Unzip the folder when you run your program

Of course! Why are you zipping the folder? It literally takes a few seconds to unzip...
Or you could simply put your files in a normal folder instead of a `.zip`.

Comment: But i Still know Where to put that code, if i put that then it will show error

Comment: Which error? [`ZipFile` is in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/archiving.html) but maybe it isn't in older versions. (that could be the cause) - If you test this code alone, it works

Comment: @AbdulHaiyan Don't use font as a [font object](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) (font is actually the content of the file). - I think this is the source of the error.

Comment: @AbdulHaiyan I edited my answer - Hope this will help you more.

Comment: I am Testing Simple Project as I have some free time, So I will not always be free, so I will reply late, and the main thing is I have copied this source code : https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/python-game-project-tic-tac-toe/  and it works in python, when I want to convert it to exe using py2exe or pyinstaller, it show the error shown, I am a begginer and I don't know certain thing, can i put your code : pygame.font.SysFont('font name', font_size)  at anywhere or specific line?

Comment: I recommend you to read [this article](https://pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_text/text.html) if you want to know more about fonts. The line `pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 11)`, for example, sets a font object (here the  font used is calibri, 11px tall). Put it at the beginning of your code to use this font like this for example: `screen.blit(  font.render('text', 0, color)),  (0, 0))` to render text on screen.