# Is there a way to access a specific file inside a.Zip file without extracting the whole thing?

Tags: python, file, zip

I am working on a game engine based on ursina. I want the different saves to be zip files so that they can be easily transferred. I do not want to extract the whole file so I want a way to access just one file using python.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Open file in zip without temporarily extracting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371860/python-open-file-in-zip-without-temporarily-extracting-it)